# Angular 2. Development in a sub local domain

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on an Angular 2 project. I need to use restful services that cannot be exposed as CORS (the local setup is a docker container that emulates the live server), thus I need to create the angular project under the same domain.

Lets say the local domain is project.dev that already has a main web site at the root.

I was asked to build an angular 2 admin section in a sub directory (say /admin) so that it can be accessed at project.dev/admin.

When the project is done it will be easy to just copy the build in that subdirectory and have it working.

The problem is while developing it. 
I'm using ancular-cli with `ng serve` but the site is served at localhost:4200, not the same domain, thus CORS issues. 
I've tried changing it using the arguments `--host` and `--port` but the ones I need, obviously, are already used by the main site.

The partial solution was to use `ng build --watch --base-href /admin/ --deploy-url /admin/` and configure `outDir` in anglular-cli.json to built the site in the proper location, but even if `--watch` is correctly rebuilding on every file changes, the browser is not refreshed as it is with ng-serve.

Unfortunately changing the server to support CORS is not an option. It is a docker container that uses JAVA as server that I'm not able to edit. Furthermore the versioned code is constantly updated by other developers.

I would like to know if it is possible to manage such a situation in a better way, mainly if is possible to serve the angular project under a local domain name while developing.
Thanks